# Single Function Call to return any possible data type

Tags: c#, function, type-conversion

Is it possible to create a function which I can call, passing an object and have that function return any data type.(I'm guessing I have to tell it the datatype to return, so below I have just passed a string for this - there may be a cleaner way to deal with this)

```
public x GetValue(Object value, string datatype)
```

Could I call this passing: `(DataRow["OrderID"], "Integer")`

Then call it again by passing: `(DataRow["CustomerName"], "String")` ?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you want to get a `DataRow` field in a strongly typed manner use the available extension method [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which also supports nullables. For example: `DataRow.Field<int>("OrderID")` or `DataRow.Field<string>("CustomerName")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called generics:

```
public T GetValue<T>(Object value)
{
    if (value == DbNull.Value)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return (T)value;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
string s = GetValue<string>(DataRow["CustomerName"]);
```

Or, as [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423213/single-function-call-to-return-any-possible-data-type/27423233#comment43288562_27423233), in this case you could use:

```
DataRow.Field<string>("CustomerName");
```

Comment: or return an object :) - Generics are better.

Comment: Will this also work with NULLABLE Values e.g. DateTime? or DbNull.Value?

Comment: @Richard: Now it does.

Comment: or simply use `DataRow.Field<string>("CustomerName")` ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yeah, true. In this case that would be the best solution.